# Is there any Azure Data factory activity to get cosmos collection list?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

Is there any option in Azure Data Factory to know the list of collections available in a particular database in Azure cosmos account?

Want to execute the particular activity - which returns list of collections in a cosmos db, every time when the Azure Data Factory pipeline get executed.

**Exact requirement:** Want to do copy data from all the collections from cosmos db but the list of collections in the cosmos db may vary as the time progress. If any new collection has been added to the cosmos db, dynamically that new collection needs to be considered as part of the copy activity without any external intervention.

While using Azure function activity in Azure Data factory to query the list of cosmos collection, it returns output like the below,

```
{
"Response": "[{\"source\": 
 {\"collectionName\":\"model1\"},\"destination\": 
 {\"fileName\":\"model1.txt\"}},{\"source\": 
{\"collectionName\":\"model2\"},\"destination\": 
{\"fileName\":\"model2.txt\"}}]"
}
```

Expected output

```
{
"Response": [
    {
     source:{collectionName:model1},
     destination: {fileName:model1.txt}
    },
  {
  source:{collectionName:model2},
  destination:{fileName:model2.txt}}]
  }
 ]
}
```

why Azure function activity returns array object as string?

p.s: when I run azure function separately from V22017 or azure portal it returns array object as array

Comment: You can add an azure cosmos db trigger function app which will run when any new item gets added to  the collection and based on that you can write your custom logic to handle data(you can write to any blob store and access the newly added all collection). Use this document as reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function

Comment: @RahulShukla, here the requirement is about taking Cosmos DB backup. Whenever the ADF pipeline get executed, it guaranteed list of collections in DB is same throughout but it may vary from execution to execution. Want to know approach how to get the collection list dynamically before every ADF pipeline execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if a direct way exists but for a workaround you can

1. Make a HTTP call to this API [Get List of Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-collections). Making a REST API call will ensure you always have latest data.

2. Parse the JSON response to get the collections. Followed by a For-Each Activity perhaps.

Edit- Adding discussion in comments to the answer

1. Make a Http Trigger function that can be called by a Web Activity.
2. Obtain AAD token inside that function
3. Call the REST Api to get list of cosmos collections
4. Return json-array as response
5. Add a For-each activity in ADF to loop over the list of collections.

Comment: I tried this, I believe by calling "Get List of collections" API of cosmos using ADF-webactivity but it didnt work. Will try again.

Comment: Yash, in order to Get List of Collections REST API call, AAD token required for each execution of pipeline. Any idea or reference document to accomplish this? as Web Activity template not supporting AAD token generation.

Comment: What if you make a HTTP triggered Function App(FA) that you can call from ADF as a web activity. In this FA you would have code to fetch AAD token, get list of collections and return it? Does that work?

Comment: Yash, Update the query with challenge while using Function App(FA) approach to query cosmos db collection. Basically Azure Function returns array object as string which cant be consumed by foreach activity as it rightly expects array. How to overcome it?

Comment: Can you use some ADF expressions or functions to convert your string to array like createArray or split?

Comment: Zackie, did that work for you? If it did then I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yash, Instead I have corrected Azure function to return 'json array' rather that 'json string' then the issue resolved.

Comment: Zackie, thats great to hear! Can you please upvote and accept the answer for better visibility for others?