# How to Feed Output of Azure Function to For-Each Activity of Data Factory?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Function using Python code to fetch the list of all collections in a Cosmos Db and feed the Output to For-Each Activity in Data factory. Ultimate goal is to Copy All Collections Dynamically to another DB.

Pseudo script

```
List1=["col1","col2","col3"]

Json=json.dumps(List1)

return func.HttpsResponse(List1)
```

The python script is working and returns a list of all collections successfully.

However, when I am calling the function through data factory, the output is coming as a String rather than a Array. For -Each activity is failing as it expects Array.

Do I need to modify the python script or Need to modify something in Data factory side?

This stackoverflow thread has something similar, but the exact answer about how to write the script is Not provided
[text](https://stackoverflow.com)
[Is there any Azure Data factory activity to get cosmos collection list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67243634/is-there-any-azure-data-factory-activity-to-get-cosmos-collection-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, when I am calling the function through data factory, the output is coming as a String rather than a Array. For -Each activity is failing as it expects Array.

I tried with below code in my environment and I got the same output in String type.

```
List1=["col1","col2","col3"]
Json=json.dumps(List1)
return func.HttpResponse(Json)
```

[image]

> Do I need to modify the python script or Need to modify something in Data factory side?

To use the above response in a ForEach, you need to convert it to array. For that use `json()` function.

Here, for sample I have converted the string response from Azure function activity to an array variable using the below expression. You can use it in ForEach expression.

```
@json(activity('Azure Function1').output.Response)
```

[image]

**Output as array:**

[image]