# Azure Pipeline DELETE FOLDERS

Tags: azure-synapse

I need your help, On Synapse I have a Bronze and Silver Storage.

In each Bronze and Silver Storage, I have directories with sub-directories: ATTRACT/OUTSTANDING/OK/KO. And in each of these sub-directories, we have sub-directories with project numbers, date etc....

Problem :

In these directories (ATTRACT/OUTSTANDING/OK/KO) which have one sub-directory and another sub-directory, there are one or more empty files or no files).

I want to build a pipeline that can delete all the empty files in the directories and subdirectories and keep only the files with data in the various ATTRACT/ OUTSTANDING/OK/KO directories.

I'd be delighted to receive any advice or demo. Thanks in advance

I want to build a pipeline that can delete all the empty files in the directories and subdirectories and keep only the files with data in the various ATTRACT/ OUTSTANDING/OK/KO directories.

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far? any errors/blockers? and please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You want to delete empty files or empty folders as well?

Comment: I want to delete both

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it might be very difficult to get all paths of empty folders and files in Synapse or ADF pipelines.

So, use any programming language like python to get the list of paths of empty folders and files and then use synapse pipeline delete activity to delete those.

You can use Azure function or databricks notebook as per your requirement to get the file paths. Append the empty folder paths list and empty file paths list and return the result list from code to pipeline.

You can go through this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75971879/how-to-feed-output-of-azure-function-to-for-each-activity-of-data-factory/75974441#75974441) to know how to use Azure function activity output in pipeline.

Give the two arrays(empty folder paths array and empty paths array) to two ForEach activities respectively in pipeline.

Inside first ForEach, take the delete activity to delete the empty folders. Take a binary dataset and create a string dataset parameter and use it for the folder path like below.

[image]

Give this dataset to the delete activity and give the `@item()` to this parameter.

[image]

Do the same for the file paths array Foreach activity.

[image]

[image]

Upon the execution of the pipeline, your Function activity or notebook activity will give the nested list containing empty folder paths list and empty file paths list. And the above for loops will delete those.